# Monorepo: Yarn workspaces not working - dependent package doesn't get installed in node_modules

Tags: react-native, package.json, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I am using monorepo created using Yarn Workspaces with Typescript which has a react-native project (*mobile* folder) and a *common* folder which contains the common files to be shared across projects. Here the *mobile* project is dependent on *common* files and I have configured it referring to this [doc](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/blog/2018/02/15/nohoist/).

When I do `yarn install` it show this error -> `An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@myapp%2fcommon: Not found".`

**Monorepo Structure:**

```
packages
|---package.json
|---Common
|      |---src
|      |---package.json
|---Mobile
|      |---src
|      |---package.json
```

**root package.json**

```
{
"name": "monorepo",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"workspaces": {
    "packages": ["packages/*"],
    "nohoist": [
        "**/react-native",
        "**/react-native/**",
    ]
}
}
```

**Common's package.json**

```
{
"name": "@myapp/common",
"version": "0.0.1",
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"license": "UNLICENSED",
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/react": "18.0.9",
  "@types/react-native": "0.67.7",
  "@reduxjs/toolkit": "1.8.1",
  "react-redux": "8.0.1"
}
}
```

**Mobile's package.json (react-native)**

```
"name": "@myapp/mobile",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
...
"dependencies": {
    "@myapp/common": "0.0.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "1.8.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    ...
}
...
```

Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your root package.json isn't really root. Make sure your folder structure looks like this:

```
package.json 
packages 
|---Common
|...
```

Comment: Got it. This resolved that error. But still `@myapp/common` is not present in Mobile's `node_modules` even after performing `yarn install` on the root folder.

Comment: That is the intended behaviour since you are hoisting everything but react-native. If you want to keep `@myapp/common` local to its package then add it to your `nohoist` list.

Comment: Yes, Nice catch. I have added it to `nohoist`.

Comment: While running the app. I am getting the error `Unable to resolve module @myapp/common from App.js. @myapp/common could not be found within the project or in these directories:\n  node_modules`. But when I checked `node_modules` folder manually it is present in it. Any idea?

Comment: Are you using any bundling tool? If so, it seems that your bundling tool is not looking for modules in your local `node_modules` folder.

Comment: Yes, `react-native` has a metro bundler which bundles everything into a single file. But If it is manually present, it should also bundle this package right?

Comment: I updated the `metro.config.js` file to check for `@myapp/common` in `node_modules` even-though it is present. Also restarted the TS server in VS code and ran the app. It worked.

Comment: Nice. To answer your question: no, just because the folder is present in your `node_modules` it does not mean that the bundler knows it should look in there for modules. Usually when having multiple `node_modules` you have an array in the bundler config file that specify where to look for modules when resolving, eg: `resolveFrom: ['packages/project1/node_modules', 'root/node_modules']`. That tells the bundler to look first in `packages/project1/node_modules` and then if the module was not found there look in `root/node_modules`

Comment: Any idea on this? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72493062/android-release-build-crashes-using-react-native-in-yarn-workspaces-monorepo Currently facing this issue.

Comment: No idea as I am not familiar with react-native. Try searching other questions maybe it is a common error.