# Android release build crashes using react-native (0.68.2) in yarn workspaces monorepo

Tags: android, react-native, monorepo, yarn-workspaces, release-builds

I am using monorepo created using Yarn Workspaces with Typescript which has a react-native (0.68.2) project (mobile folder) and a common folder which contains the common files to be shared across projects. Here the mobile project is dependent on common files and I have configured it referring to this [doc](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/blog/2018/02/15/nohoist/).

Starting with Android, the app runs fine in debug mode. When I create a release build, the apk is generated successfully. After installing the app, on opening, it crashes as soon as it opens. On observing the error, it looks like there is a problem with the bundle. I tried manually running the [bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65935694/5918233) command for packing it and tried generating the apk, but it still results in the same error.

**Error from LogCat:**

```
2022-06-03 22:36:28.457 5699-5723/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
Process: com.myapp.mobile, PID: 5699
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:248)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:29)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:277)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1422)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1200(ReactInstanceManager.java:138)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bundle was packed and placed in the wrong path which was causing this error.
Always the bundle should be packed and placed in only in this path `android\app\src\main\assets\index.android.bundle` for android. The below command will do it correctly.

```
npx  react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android\app\src\main\assets\index.android.bundle
```

Comment: Seems you're on Windows. Change path to `android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle` on Linux or MacOS.
Copy full line here: `npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle`

Comment: Yes, I had a wrong path.

Comment: i have also same problem my release apk successfully created but it run my device only not run all device so what is problem and where is problem ?

Comment: React Native when run on Android will look for the bundle in this path `android\app\src\main\assets\index.android.bundle`. If you place the bundle in a different location then you ll get that error.